# Asynctask doInBackground is too slow on real device

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am developing an android application, I am new to thread and i apologize if my question is stupid, I used **AsyncTask`s doInBackground** method for converting Stream to String and then in **onPostExecute** method,app will begetting JSON Object.

I launched my application in Emulator (API 17) and it launched prefect but when I am launching it on my smart phone (galaxy s5) it is taking too long,maybe 10 or 15 seconds.
I think doInBackground method is causing this problem.

This is my **Main Class** and doing all here :

This is where i call my Asynctask Class and send a parameter with POST method :

```
                    final ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("register_number", phoneNumber.getText().toString()));
                Log.i("LOG", "params hastttttttttt" + params.toString());
                //
                //                    Commands.readRegisterNumber(params);

                //                    new readData().execute(params);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    new readData().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
                } else {
                    new readData().execute(params);
                }
```

I define my **Asynctask** class here :

```
    private class readData extends AsyncTask<List<? extends NameValuePair>, Void, String>
```

**doInBackground** method of **Asynctask** Class :

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(List<? extends NameValuePair>... params) {
        List<? extends NameValuePair> param = params[0];

        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost method = new HttpPost("http://192.168.10.110:2233/api/register");
            method.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);
            InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            result = builder.toString();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and here is **onPostExecute** method :

```
        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { //doInBackground khorujish ro mide be in
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                G.registerNumber.clear();

                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
                StructRegisterNumber structRegisterNumber = new StructRegisterNumber();
                structRegisterNumber.status = object.optString("status");
                structRegisterNumber.code = object.optString("code");
                structRegisterNumber.message = object.optString("message");



                G.registerNumber.add(structRegisterNumber);

                StructRegisterNumber registerNumber = G.registerNumber.get(0);


                if (registerNumber.status != null && registerNumber.code != null) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(registerNumber.status) == -1) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityRegisterNumber.this, ActivityRegisterCode.class);
                        ActivityRegisterNumber.this.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }

                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I giggled when I read you were 'lunching' programs :)

Comment: Sorry i wrote it fast and i made some mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many reason why it may be slow on a real device:

1. On a real device network speed will depend on the available wifi/network range and is more susceptible to packet loss.
2. On a real device multiple applications will be running simultaneously and background thread has lower priority than services and other applications. I would recommend using SDK tool Systrace (with sched option) to see CPU cycles received by the background thread.

Comment: My wifi range and availability is good, i installed my app on several smart phones and all of them had the same problem, it takes to long to run doInBackground method, is there any problem in my code or AsyncTask class ?

Comment: Did u try network statistics in DDMS it may help you understand what is happening during network request.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly solving your problem but as you are simply loading data from the network in your AsyncTask you should consider using a networking library such as Volley which makes live a lot easier. They even have support for Gson that can automatically parse your returned Json to objects automatically.

Documentation:
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Library itself:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley